# playing board function in python

Tags: python

i am trying to create a function that draws a playing board but it wont work when i put even columns

```
def board(rows,columns):
    for x in range(rows):
        if x%2 == 0:
            for y in range(1,columns+1):
                if y%2 == 1:
                    if y != columns:
                             print(" ",end="")
                    else:
                        print(" ")              
                else:
                    print("|",end="")
        else:
            print("-"*columns)
    print("True")

board(5,5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inaki, the problem is in the columns:

```
if y%2 ==1:
    if y != columns: # BTW you might think of y<columns 
        ...
    else:
        PRINT NEW LINE.  # <- you will never get here since y%2 == 1 but columns is even
```

You might like this solution (I hope this helps you!):

```
def board(rows,columns): 
    for x in range(rows*2-1):
        if x%2 == 0: 
            print(''.join([" |"]*columns)) 
        else: 
            print("--"*columns+"-") 

board(4,4)
```